# Eclipse color Message Box

Tags: eclipse

I've downloaded eclipse Mars 64 bit for Linux and there is a very big problem. When I want to take a look at warning, or error messages I get a [dark brown box with black text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EeyA.jpg). I don't know where to change this color.

What I've just tried: 
window-preferences-java-editor and changed all colors. 
window-preferences-Appearance-Colors and Fonts and changed all dark colors.
Change Theme

Comment: which linux distro are you using?

Comment: I'm using Kubuntu 15.04 LTS

Comment: This link will help http://javaclipse.blogspot.in/2015/06/mars-on-linux.html